# SAMBA server : unable to access

Tags: samba, users, macosx

I create a user for samba,

When I connect to my share from my Mac the windows close with this message
"The operation can’t be completed because the original item for “HD” can’t be found."

HD is SDCard (NTFS)

```
[HD]
path = /media/odroid/HD/
browsable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = no
create mask = 0755
```

Accessing from a another device I have a access denied error.

How can I fix this?

I noticed a another issue with Plex Server, when add folder to the library I can see the HD folder but can't see sub-folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because my SDCard was mounted in /media ... really bad idea.
I changed the mount patch and have everything working.